# Backand- Sign in error with facebook and google

Tags: facebook, ionic-framework, backand

Im developing an app with ionic framework and im using Backand as BaaS, im using the sign in with social accounts service that provides me, but when im trying to sign in with facebook, return this error.

> The user is not signed up to 'name-of-my-app'.(signing in with facebook).

And when im trying to sign in with google, return this error:

> Object reference is not set to an instance of an object.

Also im create my own apps in facebook and google and i set the AppId and AppSecret to Backand.

I dont know why im receiving this error, actually im ussing almost the same code that the starter's Backand provides.

Comment: Do this work with Default google application?

Comment: Well i followed the instructions listed [here](http://docs.backand.com/en/latest/getting_started/security_auth/index.html#google-app-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

I have met this kind of error "Object reference is not set to an instance of an object" too, after pressing "Validate & Update" button, after editing database json model several times in the backand control panel. I could save the new model and continue, but that red error was appearing on top right at each save. My hypothesis is that also in your case the issue is related to a bug in the database model editor. I personally got rid of that kind of error by deleting the project (I had no data in it yet) and creating a new one, re-pasting and saving all at once the exact same database model json I created in the previous project.